# error parsing message: invalid character in header

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

I use ShareKit to share content on Facebook and on other social platforms.

Anyhow, recently i tested the share functionality, to ensure that it works correctly and i get this error on the facebook share screen:

> error parsing message: invalid character in header

It worked previously! I'm not quite sure, what it means or what i should do, to fix this issue.

Can anyone please help?
PS: I use it on every device (iPhone, iPad) with a version range between iOS 3.0 to iOS 5.1, but it doesn't work on any one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: Looking up in the FBDialog class, Facebook uses a different User-Agent Header. I implemented a method, which was always overriding the User-Agent. When i changed to not override the Facebook-generated User-Agent, it worked again.